# When and why did Jewish Christian separate from "mainstream" Christianity?

Tags: global-christianity, messianic-judaism

It is already the second time I read somewhere that while Christianity emerged from Judaism and in the early Church Judeo-Christians (Jewish Christians, Hebrew Christians), led by James, brother of Jesus, were "full-fledged" Christians (alongside Christians not springing from Judaism, led by Paul the Apostle), soon the ways of Judeo-Christians and "mainstream" Christianity were parting more and more, **with Judeo-Christians being officialy condemned by the time The First Council of Nicaea has finished[(source)](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%BBydzi_mesjanistyczni)**. I've even read claims that Judeo-Christians had to flee the Roman Empire from the persecution of Orthodox Christians[(source)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewish_Christian).

What were the causes of this break-up?

Comment: I don't think this squares with most histories. Are you referring to Jewish Christians who continued to practice Jewish law, and/or insisted others practice it?

Comment: @DJClayworth To those who continued to practice the Jewish law. Am I to understand that most of them did not adhere to the Council of Jerusalem and this was the cause of the break-up? My thinking was that surely there must've been a fair group of them who did adhere to the Council of Jerusalem, so, what happened with them?

Comment: You should supply some sources rather than 'i read' or 'i heard'. Part of what you state in not consistent with mainstream history.

Comment: @bradimus If it's not consistent with mainstream history then I'd be grateful to know where do I err. About the sources… There you are. Jewish Christians condemned by Council of Nicea: https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Żydzi_mesjanistyczni Jewish Christians having to flee ROman Empire from Orthodox Christians' persecution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewish_Christian

Comment: Error 1) Conflating the First Century Church in Jerusalem (when the Temple still stood and Christians had not yet been expelled from the synagogues) with 3rd Century Christians who wanted to enforce Jewish Law. Error 2) Asserting without support that 'Judeo-Christians and "mainstream" Christianity were parting'. Could it not be the case that they were absorbed instead? Paul's epistles point to this.  Error 3) Asserting that "Christians not springing from Judaism, led by Paul the Apostle", ignoring the possibility that Paul's converts likely included many Jews, especially Greek speaking Jews.

Comment: As for your source that 'Jewish Christians condemned by Council of Nicea', it is un-sourced in the Wikipedia  article -- not really a source. Concerning the Council, I am aware that it agreed on a method of calculating the date of Easter that deprecated the Jewish calendar. Beyond that, I don't recall the discussion of Judaizers being significant at the Council.

Comment: @bradimus As per Errors 1) and 3), you may be right, thank you. As per Error 2), that's a tricky case: this is something I've read in a newspaper, but I can't bring this source up now, since I can't find this article now :( I read this a few months ago :(

Answer (score 1):

I had a [wonderful discussion](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/83725/do-modern-jews-believe-in-a-priesthood-after-the-order-of-melchisedec) about the Jewish point of view of Melchizedek because of Paul's reference to him as an order of priesthood.  That discussion and Paul's letter to the Hebrews probably answer your question.  From Hebrews 7:11(KJV):

> If therefore perfection were by the Levitical priesthood, (for under
>   it the people received the law,) what further need was there that
>   another priest should rise after the order of Melchisedec, and not be
>   called after the order of Aaron?

Paul's letter is thought to be written to [Jewish Christians](http://Scholars%20believe%20it%20was%20written%20for%20Jewish%20Christians%20who%20lived%20in%20Jerusalem), and its nature would support that.  Given this perspective, "Mainstream Christianity" and "Jewish Christianity" were already in the process of separating by AD 63.

Thus, to answer your question, the cause was Jewish Christianity's continued adherence to the Mosiac Law and assumption that the Levitical and Aaronic Priesthoods superceded Christ Messiah.

Answer (score 1):

The earliest cause of the breakup between Christians and Christians was the observance of Pascha.  Some observed it as a floating observance on whatever day of the week it fell.  This means the traditional Good Friday to Sunday Resurrection could be Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, or any other combination of 3 days and 3 nights (sign of Jonah).  Others, led by Rome, beginning with Sixtus I to Anicetus to Victor observed a fixed Sunday sunrise resurrection.

see this article for more explanation, though some details are incorrect: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartodecimanism